# Merge request for questions regarding crowd control at higher difficulties

Tags: support, status-declined, questions, exact-duplicates, question-merge-request

This question: [How do monster level and act number affect crowd control reduction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80106)
is a duplicate of [How is CC reduced in higher difficulties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69990)

Please merge and close/delete the newer one.

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of a community agreement to do so (as evinced by both questions still being open), I think we can consider this declined.

This answer is here to stop Community from ever bumping this question again. Upvote it please.

Comment: Its been a while, but I think I never reported one of them as a dup, if you were looking for it to be closed. If you think they are actually different questions, can you explain why?